# uWSGI + Flask + nginx + Digital Ocean: uwsgi[1359]: --- no python application found

Tags: python, nginx, flask, uwsgi, wsgi

uWSGI + Flask + nginx + Digital Ocean: uwsgi[1359]: --- no python application found

my files look like this:

```
/projectfolder
    /myapp
        factory.py
        config.py
        __init__.py
    wsgi.py
    myapp.ini
```

factory.py:

```
def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(os.environ['APP_SETTINGS'])

    return app
```

__init__.py:

```
from myapp.factory import create_app
app = create_app()
```

wsgi.py:

```
from myapp import app as application

if __name__ == '__main__':
    application.run()
```

myapp.ini

```
[uwsgi]
module = wsgi:application

master = true
processes = 5

socket = myapp.sock
chmod-socket = 660
vacuum = true

die-on-term = true

env = APP_SETTINGS=myapp.config.Config
```

I tried running `uwsgi --socket 0.0.0.0:5000 --protocol=http -w wsgi:app` and it seems to work, but using nginx and uwsgi, all I get is `no python application found`. All I can gather from this is that somehow, my import is broken in wsgi.py. I'm just not sure how.

Comment: Change `wsgi:app` to `wsgi:application` and see if that fixes your issue

Comment: @TarunLalwani My mistake. I already had it set as wsgi:application, and still get this issue. Fixed my post.

Comment: Are you setting the python path in uWSGI to look in the directory containing the ``wsgi.py`` file? If you aren't and uWSGI is run from a different directory, not sure it will find it.

Comment: Try adding `pp=/absolute/path/to/projectfolder` and `chdir=/absolute/path/to/projectfolder` to your `uwsgi.ini`